# Having trouble running a program in MARs

Tags: macos, mips, sql-server-mars

I have downloaded MARs and also installed Java. I have a M1 Macbook Air.

My issue is that when I do write a code, the buttons where you can assemble and press go are all greyed out. This is for an academic assignment

[image]

Comment: where is the code???

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your code first as a file on your computer (filename.asm). Notice the asterisk in the name of the tab. It means your code has unsaved changes.